# Probability of pulling one of each suit with 7 replaced cards

Tags: combinatorics

A card is selected at random from a standard 52-card deck. The suit (H,S,D or C) is recorded and the card is replaced in the deck. This is done a total of seven times. Find the probability that all four suits occur among the cards selected.

So the way I figure the answer is this:

If we consider a sequence of suits, the length of the sequence is 7 with the set of suits being 4. We want to take the quotient of combinations of 7 cards where at least one of each suit is chosen over the total number of combinations of 7 cards. Thus, we have k=7,n=4

$$\dfrac{\dbinom{k-1}{n-1}}{\dbinom{n+k-1}{k}}
=\dfrac{\dbinom{6}{3}}{\dbinom{10}{7}}
=0.167$$
However, I know this is wrong by a practical test which consistently returns approximately 0.51. Why is the given approach incorrect?

Also, LaTeX isn't cooperating on the fractions. Can't figure that one out either

[Edit: Protip - use `\dbinom{}{}` rather than mess with `\begin{pmatrix}...`, and also wrap LaTeX between \$ delimitaters]

Comment: The $\binom{10}{7}$ configurations counted by Stars and Bars are not all equally likely.

Answer (score 2):

While the stars-and-bars method will count the number of distinct results, such as `three hearts and four spades`, or `five diamonds, one club, and a heart`, &c. those are not all equiprobable events.   This is not helpful for evaluating the required probability.

---

Ignore the face values. There are $4^7$ ways to pick a suit from $\heartsuit, \diamondsuit,\clubsuit,\spadesuit$ seven times with repetition.

But we want to ensure no suit is left out.

Counting that is as easy as PIE*:  $4^7-\binom{4}{3}3^7+\binom{4}{2}2^7-\binom{4}{1}1^7$

(* the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion)

$$\mathsf P_\text{answer}=\dfrac{4^7-4\cdot 3^7+6\cdot 2^7-4}{4^7}$$